# jQuery UI datepicker function calling dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

**This is function which is reposible for create row dynamically.**

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    var count = 1;
    var row = $("table#myTable tr:eq(1)");          
    $(document).on('click', '#addrow', function() {
       $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr class="prototype" id="' + count + '"> <td align="center" ><input type="text" size="10" name="grnno[' + count + ']" id="grnno"  class="required" align="right"/></td><td align="center" ><input type="text" name="paymentdateid="datepicker size="10" class="datepicker" align="right" /></td><td align="center"><select id="bankname" name="bankname"><option value="">Select Bank Name</option><option value="SBI">SBI</option><option value="UBI">UBI</option><option value="UCO">UCO</option><option value="HDFC">HDFC</option></select></td><td align="center" ><input type="text" name="amount[' + count + ']" id="amount[' + count + ']" size="10" class="required" align="right"/></td><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="id[]" value="' + count + '" class="id" /></td></tr>');
       count++;
    });     
});
```

**now I want to attach this function with the field "Payment Date" as I need the datepicker dynamically**
.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        inline: true
    });         
});
```

**I have to mentioned here  customizing the append function is not possible .**

Comment: doesn't make sense to me, be more clear & specific.

Comment: Can you modify the document.ready function at all or just not the append?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a widget, you need to initialize it once the element is added to the dom.

So

- Use appendTo() to get back the tr that is added
- use class for the datepicker instead of id since ID of an element must be unique
- after appending the tr find the datepicker element and initialize the widget

Try

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var count = 1;
    var row = $("table#myTable tr:eq(1)");

    $(document).on('click', '#addrow', function () {
        var $tr = $('<tr class="prototype" id="' + count + '"> <td align="center" ><input type="text" size="10" name="grnno[' + count + ']" id="grnno"  class="required" align="right"/></td><td align="center" ><input type="text" name="paymentdate classs="datepicker size="10" class="datepicker" align="right" /></td><td align="center"><select id="bankname" name="bankname"><option value="">Select Bank Name</option><option value="SBI">SBI</option><option value="UBI">UBI</option><option value="UCO">UCO</option><option value="HDFC">HDFC</option></select></td><td align="center" ><input type="text" name="amount[' + count + ']" id="amount[' + count + ']" size="10" class="required" align="right"/></td><td align="center"><input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteRow(this)"></td><td style="display:none;"><input type="text" name="id[]" value="' + count + '" class="id" /></td></tr>').appendTo('#myTable tbody');
        $tr.find(".datepicker").datepicker({
            inline: true
        });
        count++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot One more question to you sir...what is the purpose of the $document.on() function? Is this doing same as .bind()?